# Inserting an external variable in XML address (concatenation)

Tags: php, xml

So its me again, i'm facing a wired issue while calling an external XML file into my PHP code. Thing is, same way of concatenating a variable with URL and then calling the URL as json works fine but when i try to concatenate a variable in URL of XML, it returns error. Here is what works fine (json):

```
$city = input[1]; // Input is an external input...
$liveWeather = file_get_contents("http://weather3.pricop.info/api.php?city=$city");
```

Here is XML one which does 'not' works:

```
$city = input[1];
$xmlString = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=$city&mode=xml&units=imperial&cnt=9");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
```

And the error is:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/u369795042/public_html/weather.php on line 18
```

Maybe its a dumb question but i tried finding about that around and couldn't find this simple problem's issue.

Comment: Can you show us the xml file?

Comment: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=$city&mode=xml&units=imperial&cnt=9

Actually in that URL, change $city with any city name and check the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
```

---

I've made this php file and it worked fine:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$city = "New+York";
$xmlString = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=$city&mode=xml&units=imperial&cnt=9");
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
print_r($xml);
unset($xml);
exit();
?>
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Added my testcode. This works fine. Could you try this?

Comment: Well @Eddy i got it, thing is that i am fetching $city from elsewhere, if i define $city by a string like city = "NewYork" it works fine but when i define $city = $input[1], it fails to load it even after getting input.

Comment: I need more code to help you on this. Are you sure $input[1] is a (the right) string. What does echo '<pre>'; print_r($input[1]); echo '</pre>'; say?

Comment: Yes i use $city = $input[1] and it echo's same city name, the same $city variable works for other URL, i already know whats wrong, thing is that when PHP script starts, it just loads input[1] and sends it to XML page (While its null) and so page return 404 error, on other hand, the URL above (json) one works fine even with NIL input. I wanna figure out a way to check URL for XML only if it contains a string, otherwise return just a random city or just New+York.